# Combinations of characters (Math)

Tags: math

If I have 37 different characters and I need to create all possible words from that having max length of 15, what will be number pf total words?

Supoose, I have X=2 characters, and Y=2 max length, then possible outcomes are:
A
AA
B
BB
AB
BA

So Z=6 number of total outomces.

Now if value of X=37 and Y=15, what will be value of Z???

Comment: Can you come up with a way of counting the words of a *specific* length, say `3` ? Then you can just apply this for `1` to `15` and sum the results

Comment: i've flagged this post for migration - http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be much better suited for a pure math question.

Answer (score 3):

It's sum(37^i) for i=1..15. For your example: 2^1 + 2^2 = 6.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to Bartosz' answer, a simple formula for the sum is

```
n = ((1-X^(Y+1)) / (1-X)) - 1
```

Comment: might help him further if you specify what X and Y represent above

Comment: they represent exactly the variables, he defined in his question: X is the character count, Y is the word length

Comment: Sorry - I totally missed that. Still early in the morning here. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Another simple formula for the summation is

```
x * (x^y - 1)
-------------
    x - 1
```

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5Ei+for+i+1+to+y+